# PHP accessing one element in an array

Tags: php, arrays

In this example i am reading in data from a text file and then I am outputting the data bases on whether the data is from a male or a female into a table. I am having trouble with the line: echo " $male_votes['class-int']";
I am receiving a parse error. I am just trying to access the first element in the array $male_votes with is named "class-int".

```
<?php
//Keep track of male votes
$male_votes =array("class-int" => 0, "class-gui" => 0, "class-net" => 0, "class-oop"=> 0);
//Keep track of the female votes
$female_votes = array("class-int" => 0, "class-gui" => 0, "class-net" => 0, "class-oop" => 0);

//Open the file for reading
$myfile = fopen("results.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr> <th> <strong> Class </strong> </th>";
echo "<th> <strong> Males </strong> </th>";
echo "<th> <strong> Females <strong> </th>";
echo "<th> <strong> Total </strong> </th> </tr>";
echo "<tr> <td> Internet Development </td>";

// Output one line until end-of-file
while(!feof($myfile)) {
   //Read a single line from the file
   $line = fgets($myfile);

   //Make sure we didn't read an empty line
   if(strlen($line) >0)
   {
       $class = substr($line,0,9);
       $gender = substr($line,10,1);
       echo "$class<br>";
       if($gender == 'M')
       {
            $male_votes[$class]++;
       }
       else
       {
           $female_votes[$class]++;
       }
   }
}
echo "<td> $male_votes['class-int']</td>";

// echo"<td> $male_votes[$class] </td>";
// echo"<td> $female_votes[$class]</td>";
// echo "<td> $male_votes[$class] + $female_votes[$class]";

fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
echo "<td> ${male_votes['class-int']}</td>";
```

Or like this:

```
echo "<td> {$male_votes['class-int']}</td>";
```

Or like this:

```
echo '<td> '.$male_votes['class-int'].'</td>';
```

Comment: How would I add two of my arrays to make a total. I want to add my male votes and female votes.

Comment: Depends on if You want to add them together or write them separatedly.

Comment: This would sum both.. `echo '<td>'.($male_votes['class-int'] + $female_votes['class-int']).'</td>';` - IF You konw that votes are actually numbers/numerics/integers. ... and if You want to add votes one after another, than just leave a blank space within echoed string or separator of Your choice, than write in female votes, just as male votes.